# Giving merchant account information to web programmer

Tags: credit-card, fraud

Our web programmer needs our merchant account information to set up our ecommerce site.  He is asking for the "processor name", "processor ID" and "merchant ID".  If I provide him with the information is he going to be able to access our merchant account and take money out?  ie. charging refunds to his credit card.

Comment: You should not give him this information.  Have him design the system so this information can be filled by your company at a later time.

Comment: Well it seems normal that you need some sort of priviliges to setup a system, but why the processor name... Looks like [pretexting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)#Pretexting) to me, but that's probably too far-fetched

Answer (score 5):

Could you be more specific as to your situation? How is the web programmer in question related to your company? Is he a permanent staff or a contractor? A proper contract should protect you reasonably well from such threats.

In more technical terms, there is no reason why your programmer needs your actual credentials. Sites like PayPal provides [sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/) environments to test out transactions without actually involving actual money. Your programmer should be able to code the transaction system and provide a configuration interface where you can add in the actual details yourself later on.